# Can I create an android, ios and web with the same codebase of kotlin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created an android app with `kotlin` and it is on-demand to make it available for `Web-app` and IOS as well. So I searched on Google to find a way to do that and I got something like **Kotlin for multiplatform** and after reading that I got a point that it is possible to create an IOS app too with the same codebase.

But I don't know that the same codebase can also work for the web app or not? Or the question can be that "Is it possible to make an app for all the 3 platforms with the same codebase?"

Or I should switch to `Flutter`?
But if I switch to flutter then I have to start migrating it from scratch. Which would be so time consuming. But I have listened, that we have to write the code for once on flutter and run it anywhere. While with kotlin I have to change many things for different platforms?

**Am I right? What would be a better approach for the long term?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Kotlin Multiplatform**, you can get up to *~80%* shared code between platforms, theoretically.

Yes, this means that generally your UI, but other platform specific things also will have to be rewritten for every platform.

In your case, I think it makes sense to move towards this direction. You'll have to adapt your kotlin code a bit, make the UI for Web and iOS, but you'll get native quality, and more control over the platforms.
At least this is what I would choose if I already have a kotlin codebase, let me know if you have more questions

Comment: You mean if I choose the way to go with kotlin. So it will take less time than recreating it with flutter? And with kotlin when I update the project then I have to do changes to all the 3 platforms. So will it not take more time than flutter?  I agree with your answer that if you would be in my place you choose kotlin as a time-saving approach Thanks for that. But I also want to know that would also be good for the long term?

Comment: Yes, if you think about long term, probably at some point you'll miss some of the native solutions.
But I'd say it depends on what you're planning to build:
- For the best quality/efficiency ratio probably KMP is the best
- If you just care about efficiency, flutter can be a good candidate, but if you hit a roadblock, going through the native road will be a headache

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, Now I think I should go with kotlin.  

Comment: @mr.groot, also I wrote a blog about these considerations, might be a useful 6min read: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/considerations-for-an-effective-mobile-app-development-fcc7dce18d21