# What is the best way for creating a web app with kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I have made an android app with kotlin and now I need a website and iOS devices. So I was thinking about migrating the app to `Flutter` but before doing it I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67209177/14617810) and got an answer that we can create an iOS app with the existing android app with `Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile` By just writing code for UI and other platform required codes for iOS.

But now the question is **How can I create a web app with the existing android app?**

So for that, I searched and get that we can make web apps too with `Ktor` or `Spring Boot` But as I know, For that I have to write HTML and CSS for UI?

Or there is a more efficient way for this that I don't know Or the way of migrating the app to flutter would be best for a long-term plan?

Answer (score 0):

With **Kotlin Multiplatform**, you could share the non-platform/non-UI code between Android, iOS, Web. This means that it's up to you what you use for writing the UI on iOS and web (you can use angular, react or any other framework you prefer).

For examples of how to do this:

- https://github.com/bugsnag/kotlin-multiplatform-example - A Kotlin
  multiplatform example app that targets Android, ReactJS, iOS
- https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground - A KMP example app that targets Android, iOS, macOS with SwiftUI on iOS